# SQL use distinct on only one specific field

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

How can I select only one line by `shortDesc` field? I don't care about which line, but only I need only one line.

My table extract would be

```
|longDescr|shortDesc|
|---------|---------|
| First 1 | first   |
| First 2 | first   |
| First 3 | first   |
| First 4 | first   |
| Second 1| second  |
| Second 2| second  |
| Second 3| second  |
| Second 4| second  |
| Third 1 | third   |
| Third 2 | third   |
| Third 3 | third   |
```

And what I am expected is as cursor result:

```
|longDescr|shortDesc|
|---------|---------|
| First 1 | first   |
| Second 1| second  |
| Third 1 | third   |
```

I really don't know how I could write my SQL query. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one using `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT MIN(longDescr) AS longDescr, shortDesc
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY shortDesc
```

Output:

```
╔═══════════╦═══════════╗
║ LONGDESCR ║ SHORTDESC ║
╠═══════════╬═══════════╣
║ First 1   ║ first     ║
║ Second 1  ║ second    ║
║ Third 1   ║ third     ║
╚═══════════╩═══════════╝
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9a483/1)

You can use `MIN()` or `MAX()` function as per your requirement.

Comment: `MIN()` or `MAX()` function do the trick! However, I was not able to use the `group by` feature

Answer (score 2):

```
Select longDescr,shortDesc from
(Select Row_Number() Over(Partition By shortDesc order by shortDesc) as Rows ,*
 from TableName ) t 
where Rows=1;
```

Comment: +1 for a more versatile answer, especially if you need to pull back more than just a couple columns.

Comment: Or if you also need to pull back the values from the row that contains that specific shortDesc in addition to it, which I do quite often.